# sphinx: sorting by range of an association

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Let's say I have a 1:many relation:

Tree:Apples

Tree/Apple each have an primary key ID column and apple has some date attribute/column (created_at).

Using sphinx,  I want to retrieve all trees, sorted by the number apples created during a given period of time.  So, for example:

All trees, sorted by the total number of apples created between 1/1/2010 and 1/1/2011.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

So you have two tables

```
create table tree ( tree_id int unsigned primary key,...);
```

and

```
create table apple ( apple_id int unsigned primary key, tree_id int unsigned, created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,...);
```

So can then just build an index on apples

```
sql_query = select apple_id,tree_id,unix_timestamp(created_at) as created_at from apple
```

then run group by queries on it

```
$cl->setGroupBy('tree_id',SPH_GROUPBY_ATTR,'@count DESC');
```

The @count virtual attribute will give you the number of apples on that tree.

to set the filter

```
$cl->setFilterRange('created_at',strtotime('2010-01-01'),strtotime('2011-01-01'));
```

Also because you not using it, can set ranking to none

```
$cl->setRankingMode(SPH_RANK_NONE);
```

To be clear you just use a blank query

```
$res = $cl->Query('',$index);
```

Comment: your count attribute doesn't take into consideration the date range?

Comment: Yes it does, the setFilterRange applies to setGroupBy